# Semantical Error line 0, col 97 near 'prix WHERE prix': Error: Class App\Entity\Produit has no association named prix

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I try to join two entities with Symfony QueryBuilder. I've created a function findAllQuery in order to filter a research, but I get the error that my entity doesn't have any association. I saw already some similar questions but I can't resolve the problem.

Thanks for help !

**Publication entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PublicationRepository::class)
 */
class Publication
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datePublication;

  
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="publications")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Produit::class, inversedBy="publications")
     */
    private $produit;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDatePublication(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datePublication;
    }

    public function setDatePublication(?\DateTimeInterface $datePublication): self
    {
        $this->datePublication = $datePublication;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduit(): ?Produit
    {
        return $this->produit;
    }

    public function setProduit(?Produit $produit): self
    {
        $this->produit = $produit;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Produit Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProduitRepository::class)
 */
class Produit
{
    public function hydrate(array $init)
    {
        foreach ($init as $key => $value) {
            $method = "set" . ucfirst($key);
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $vendu;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Commande::class, inversedBy="produits")
     */
    private $commande;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Type::class, inversedBy="produit")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Publication::class, mappedBy="produit", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $publication;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $prix;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Publication::class, mappedBy="produit")
     */
    private $publications;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->publications = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVendu(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->vendu;
    }

    public function setVendu(?bool $vendu): self
    {
        $this->vendu = $vendu;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    public function setPhoto(?string $photo): self
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCommande(): ?Commande
    {
        return $this->commande;
    }

    public function setCommande(?Commande $commande): self
    {
        $this->commande = $commande;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?Type
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?Type $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getPrix(): ?float
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    public function setPrix(float $prix): self
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Publication[]
     */
    public function getPublications(): Collection
    {
        return $this->publications;
    }

    public function addPublication(Publication $publication): self
    {
        if (!$this->publications->contains($publication)) {
            $this->publications[] = $publication;
            $publication->setProduit($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePublication(Publication $publication): self
    {
        if ($this->publications->removeElement($publication)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($publication->getProduit() === $this) {
                $publication->setProduit(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Publication Repository**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Publication;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Entity\ProduitSearch;
use App\Entity\Produit;



/**
 * @method Publication|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Publication|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Publication[]    findAll()
 * @method Publication[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PublicationRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Publication::class);
    }
 
    public function findAllQuery (ProduitSearch $search){
        if ($search->getMaxPrix()){
            return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('publication')
            ->select('produit')
            ->from('App\Entity\Produit','produit') 
            ->join('produit.prix','prix')
            ->andWhere('prix <= :maxPrix')
            ->setParameter('maxPrix', $search->getMaxPrix())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        }
        return $this->findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not right. You can only join on relations and not on fields. I guess you try to get publications where the price of any produit is lower than maxPrix.

```
return $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('publication')
    ->join('publication.produit','produit')
    ->andWhere('produit.prix <= :maxPrix')
    ->setParameter('maxPrix', $search->getMaxPrix())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```